# l7-filter debian don't work

Tags: debian, iptables

I install and configure l7-filter:

```
sudo apt-get install l7-filter-userspace l7-protocols
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/l7-filter-userspace/examples/sample-l7-filter.conf /etc/l7-filter.conf
sudo l7-filter -f /etc/l7-filter.conf -q 2 -v
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 2
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 2
```

l7-filter loads all protocol and doesn't give error:

```
Got packet, had no ct:  udp      17 src=192.168.1.1 dst=8.8.8.8
sport=45659 dport=53
Got packet, had no ct:  udp      17 src=192.168.1.1 dst=8.8.8.8
sport=34234 dport=53
```

Comment: What happened? What did you expect to happen? Does the "sample-l7-filter.conf" actually do anything? If there were no errors how do you know it didn't work?

Comment: l7-filter does not set markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try load ip_conntrack_netlink and nf_conntrack_ipv4 modules:

```
sudo modprobe ip_conntrack_netlink
sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

Comment: How did you find them?

Comment: @bindbn In Ubuntu 10.10, when run l7-filter I get the WARNING